# JWPlayer fires onPlay() twice. How to get it to only fire once?

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using jwplayer for a video and I'm trying to track the number of seconds the player is playing. In the example, when you click the On/Off button, it does advance properly, but when you click Play on the video player, best I can figure is that the onPlay fires twice. (if you add a console.log or alert to the function, it'll show twice)

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm lost now!

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zqgvwpa6/2/

the HTML:

```
<div id='videoman' class="videoman"></div>
<p id="counter">0</p>
counter is: <button id="clicker">Off</button>
```

the JS:

```
$(function(){

    jwplayer('videoman').setup({
        file: 'https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/XjiIpRcb-1080.mp4',
        image: 'https://www.jwplayer.com/wp-content/themes/jwplayer-20/assets/images/home-video_header.jpg',
        title: 'Jawns',
        width: '30%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
    });

    jwplayer('videoman').onPlay(function(){ startCounting(); });
    jwplayer('videoman').onPause(function(){ stopCounting(); });
    jwplayer('videoman').onComplete(function(){ stopCounting(); });

    $('#clicker').click(function(){ 
        if ($(this).text() == 'Off') {
            startCounting(); $(this).text('On');
        } else {
            stopCounting(); $(this).text('Off');
        }
    });

    var videocount = 0;
    var counter;
    var startCounting = function(){
        window.counter = setInterval(saveTime, 1000); //save every 2 seconds
    }

    var stopCounting = function(){
        clearInterval(window.counter);
    }

    function saveTime() {
        videocount += 1;
        $('#counter').text(videocount);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The player will fire this twice. You should set a flag for the first time it has been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a boolean variable to control the count process, and just have your polling function check the variable. This way you can set/unset that variable from multiple sources without worrying about running functions multiple times.

See http://jsfiddle.net/y6s4jymc/1/

Specifically,

```
var startCounting = function(){
    countEnabled  = true;
}

var stopCounting = function(){
    countEnabled  = false;        
}

var runCounter = function () {
    if (countEnabled) {
        saveTime();
    }
}

var counter = window.setInterval(runCounter, 2000); //save every 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried your fiddle and it wasn't running properly for me. Although the counter did advance, it didn't stop when the player stopped playing. I rewrote it and it performs the way I assume the way you intended it to. I'm still learning, so forgive my clunky code. Take a look here: [https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/syzcd1q7/](http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/syzcd1q7/)*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jwplayer('videoman').setup({
        file: 'https://content.jwplatform.com/videos/XjiIpRcb-1080.mp4',
        image: 'https://www.jwplayer.com/wp-content/themes/jwplayer-20/assets/images/home-video_header.jpg',
        title: 'Jawns',
        width: '50%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
    var //runOnce = false, // false if no play has fired, true if 1st play fired
        videocount = 0,
        counter,
        $click = $('#clicker'),
        $reset = $('#reset'),
        status = jwplayer('videoman').getState;

        jwplayer('videoman').onReady(function() {
            jwplayer('videoman').pause();
        });

    jwplayer('videoman').onPlay(function() { // Whenever playing, the next 2 lines will determine if it's the first play or the second play
            console.log('[[PLAY FIRED]]');
       //if (runOnce === false) {
            //runOnce = true;
            $click.text('ON');
            window.counter = setInterval(saveTime, 1000);
        //}
    });

    jwplayer('videoman').onPause(function () {
        $click.text('OFF');
        clearInterval(window.counter);
        runOnce = false;
        console.log('[[PAUSED FIRED]]');
    });

    jwplayer('videoman').onIdle(function () {
        $click.text('OFF');
        clearInterval(window.counter);
        runOnce = false;
        console.log('[[IDLING]]');
    });

    $click.on('click', function () {
        if (status != 'PLAYING') {
            jwplayer('videoman').play();
        } else {
            jwplayer('videoman').pause();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $reset.on('click', function () {
        jwplayer('videoman').stop();
        clearInterval(window.counter);
        runOnce = false;
        videocount = 0;
        $('#counter').text(videocount);
    });

    function saveTime() {
        videocount += 1;
        $('#counter').text(videocount);
    }
});
```

The behavior you are experiencing is a [known bug](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6551609-onplay-firing-twice-any-fix-yet) that won't be fixed until the next version (v. 6.13). I attempted to use the [suggested fix](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6551609-onplay-firing-twice-any-fix-yet), but it still fired twice upon loading (not desirable) and successive plays fired only once (desirable). Despite failing to suppress the second play from firing, it works. Hopefully the code I provided can help, good luck.

*Included comments and relevant link.